# Downloaded PDFs in .zip are corrupt

Tags: c#, html, pdf, zip

I created a HTML5 online portal for suppliers, where they can upload and download as many files as they want. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to show you screenshots. But here's the problem:
If there are 2 or more files uploaded then the programm should create a .zip file with all the PDFs inside. It gets created properly and the files are all inside, **but** they are corrupt, means I can't open them. Besides that, they got a filesize of 1 KB.

```
String zipFile = String.Format(@"{0}.zip", Guid.NewGuid());
String zipPath = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}", Data.Properties.Settings.Default.DownloadPath, zipFile);


using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(zipPath, FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Data.Properties.Settings.Default.SelectionTMPDatabase))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT [FileName], [File] FROM {0} WHERE [DownloadId] = @downloadId", Data.Properties.Settings.Default.SelectionFileDatabaseTable), con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@downloadId", downloadID);

                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        if (dr["FileName"] != null && dr["FileName"] != DBNull.Value && fileNames.Contains(dr["FileName"].ToString()))
                        {
                            ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.CreateEntry(dr["FileName"].ToString());

                            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(entry.Open()))
                            {
                                writer.Write((byte[])dr["File"]);
                            }
```

That's the part where the .zip is created. I hope you can help me! If you have any questions just ask!

Comment: I would first refactor to reduce nesting. Split out retrieving data from the database and writing it to the file

Comment: Are you sure that the byte array in `dr["File"]` contains all bytes ?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an empty zip entry, then writing to it with the contents of the column "File" - is that really what you're intending to do?

How about you get get full path of `dr["FileName"]` and then simply do

```
archive.CreateEntryFromFile(dr["fileName"], fullPathToFile);
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I'm intending. I worked with this method a few months ago and it created everything properly. Btw there is no `CreateEntryFromFile`-method.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485720(v=vs.110).aspx, you need to import `System.IO.Compression`. I would check if you can create a PDF file directly from the File data then, as I imagine either the database or DataReader encoding is muddling some characters.